# Compiling Scss in Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

so I was trying to get my webpack config file to create a compiled css file so that later on when I added the webpack-dev-server I would be able to compile both my js and css and put it into a dist folder. I thought this would be simple enough so I had this so far in my webpack.config.js file

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./js/app.js', './scss/main.scss'],
  output: {
    filename: 'dist/bundle.js'
  },
  module: {

    rules: [
      /*
      your other rules for JavaScript transpiling go in here
      */
      { // regular css files
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          loader: 'css-loader?importLoaders=',
        }),
      },
      { // sass / scss loader for webpack
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ // define where to save the file
      filename: 'dist/[name].bundle.css',
      allChunks: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

But when running the webpack command I'm getting

```
throw new _ValidationError2.default(ajv.errors, name);
```

I'm not sure why but I assumed it was maybe because I was using something outdated so I went searching and well I couldn't find anything that worked.

Oh also I'm on a windows computer and here is my package.json

```
 {
  "name": "portfolio_site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^3.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Thanks in advance I just want to know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

in your webpack config you have :

```
{ // regular css files
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          loader: 'css-loader?importLoaders=',
        }),
      },
      { // sass / scss loader for webpack
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
      }
```

Instead it should be :

```
{ // regular css files
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: 'css-loader?importLoaders=',
        }),
      },
      { // sass / scss loader for webpack
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
      }
```

"loader" has been deprecated.

ref : https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/569

Comment: I've tried this but when I do I now get the error C:\Users\me\Desktop\coding\html\portfolio_site\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\lib\helpers.js:15
  return chunk.isInitial() || chunk.parents.length === 0;

Comment: Not sure if it helps but try deleting the node_modules folder and do an `npm install` or `yarn` based on what you are using and check if you still get the error

Comment: Thanks for the input @nizantz but the error still happens. Maybe this is a windows issue?